# Rosen graph exercise

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question related to Rosen's exercise:

Is every zero–one square matrix that is symmetric and
has zeros on the diagonal the adjacency matrix of a simple
graph?

The answer is yes. However, I wonder what about directed graphs? They can also be symmetric and have zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: Same idea applies for Digraphs, but loose the requirement of symmetry. The directed edges are now defined in the obvious way.

Comment: The adjacency matrix $A$ for a digraph does not need to be symmetric. Say, for example, that ones below the main diagonal at position $A_{i,j}$ (i.e. $i<j$) indicates an edge $i \rightarrow j$ and a one above the main diagonal at position $A_{i,j}$ (i.e. $i>j$) indicates the edge $j\rightarrow i$